# Irp information return PVOID

Tags: c++, kernel, wdk, windows-kernel, kmdf

I'm writing Windows kernel driver in C++ and I have to return **PVOID** which has information about address in memory. Unfortunately, **Irp->IoStatus.Information** is only able to handle **ULONG** which results in shortened address for example: **0x2e341990000** is shortened to **0x41990000**. It is very important to keep the address full otherwise user mode client would not be able to find address in memory. Is there any way to return full PVOID to client?

Driver code:

```
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    ULONG bytesIO = 0;
    auto stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    switch (stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {
        case IOCTL_SHELL:
        {
            auto len = stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength;
            if (len < sizeof(Data))
            {
                DbgPrint("[-] Received too small buffer\n");
                status = STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
                break;
            }

            auto data = (Data*)stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.Type3InputBuffer;
            if (data == nullptr)
            {
                DbgPrint("[-] Received empty buffer\n");
                status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                break;
            }

            PVOID buf = SetMemoryAddress(data);

            bytesIO = (ULONG)buf; // Buffer is shortened here

            DbgBreakPoint();

            break;
        }
    }

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = bytesIO;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
```

Client code:

```
    HANDLE hDevice;
    BOOL success;

    hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\Driver", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;

    Data data;
        // Fill data structure here

    PVOID retn;
    PVOID buffer = { 0 };
    success = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_SHELL, &data, sizeof(data), NULL, 0, (LPDWORD)&retn, NULL);
    printf("0x%x\n", retn); // Shortened address

    return success;
```

I tried using buffered IOCTL methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your `retn` variable is not a memory address it is the number of bytes returned from the `DeviceIoControl` call. It is also of double word size (32bits) not equivalent with a void pointer on a modern 64bit machine.

The output data is written into the fifth argument which is optional and you seem to have provided `NULL` to.

You might want to initialize the value at `retn` so you can see if it is changed by your `DeviceIoControl` call, even if you provide nowhere to write output to.

```
DWORD bufffer_size_ouf =  0;
PVOID retn = (PVOID)&buff_size_out;
```